# unable to start jbossas 7.1.1 through eclipse keplar

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am using JBOSS 7.1.1 with eclipse keplar but it fails to start .
I tried these steps :

1) changed JDK version currently using 1.7

2) tried to start by changing by default ports as shown in second pic.

but Jboss is not starting please guide...

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66ipK.png)

[jboss settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28eWp.gif)

Comment: Can you please post the logs of your server?

Answer (score 1):

step 1) Check for JDK.

windows -> preferences -> Java -> installed JREs. 
Then Search, point to your JDK installation and select that result as the default one.

step 2) Then you should also check under your server run-time environment if it's using the same jre selected above (from the JDK)

in my case there was a mismatch between these two.